# Kubernetes: How to use php (Laravel) app from persist volume and update code changes when pulling new image

Tags: php, laravel, docker, kubernetes

Im new to Kubernetes and i try to run Laravel application from persistent volume. I got it working and i will have now the code running from persistent volume and i can scale it.

I have nginx running in own pods and share the same persistent volume.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    tier: backend
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: laravel-pv-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: laravel-pv-claim
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
          items:
          - key: config
            path: site.conf
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: laravel-pv-volume
          mountPath: /code
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

My Laravel deployment includes initContainers which has command to copy Laravel source code from /var/www to /code which is the persistent volume path

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: laravel-pv-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: laravel-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: registry.digitalocean.com/xxx/laravel-test:3.0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: laravel-pv-volume
          mountPath: /code
      initContainers:
      - name: install
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: registry.digitalocean.com/xxx/laravel-test:3.0
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -R /var/www/. /code && chown -R www-data:www-data /code"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: laravel-pv-volume
          mountPath: /code
```

How can i create new pods with new code after the Laravel image changes and code will be updated, somehow i think that after this i should make new persistent volume path for mount that will run the code for the new pods, and when old pods will be terminated, last one will delete the "old" code from persistent volume. But also i don't know that will the pods now that which one is last?

My workaround this could be that if my Laravel image updates to next version, i will add command to clear the /code folder, but that will not be the best practice and will couse downtime.

`command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -rf /code/*" && "cp -R /var/www/. /code && chown -R www-data:www-data /code"]`

Answer (score 2):

*I understand from where these practices come. But you should do differently on Kubernetes.*

### Code in Docker images

When you updated your PHP code, don't put it on a PersistentVolume, instead, build a new Docker image, with e.g. `docker build -t <myapp>:<new version> .` and when you have pushed the image to a registry, you can update the `image:`  field in the `Deployment`. Avoid putting code on Persistent Volumes, and most likely you will not need a Persistent Volume Claim in your `Deployment` at all.

Most likely you want a `COPY` command in your `Dockerfile` to put your code in the container, something like (don't know your paths):

```
COPY code/ opt/app/myapp
```